# Can't get a component derived from a base class with generics defined as an interface in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to understand why I cannot get a component on a gameobject that derives from a base class that has a generic tied to an interface.

I have the following setup for my class:

```
MyClass : Node<IMyInterface>
```

with

```
abstract Node<T> : Monobehaviour where T : IMyInterface
```

Then in a separate component on the same gameobject as `MyClass` i have:

```
GetComponent<Node<IMyInterface>>()
```

This always returns null when i have `MyClass` attached to the same GameObject. I also cannot drag the component to a public field of type `Node<IMyInterface>` either even though it seems to suggest I can because when I drag it over the field it highlights it as if I am able to set it there.

Why does it not allow this ? I don't see anything wrong here as the types match perfectly fine...

Comment: unity not support that , interface on inspector , so you need found other solution. maybe this help you
https://github.com/TheDudeFromCI/Unity-Interface-Support

Comment: `GetComponent<Node<IMyInterface>>()` <-- this not work on generic of generic type , C# not very smart, you only can use like this `GetComponent<MyClass>()`

Comment: Oh so I have to use a precise type that implements the interface?

Comment: as far as I know , yes . need precise type or interface or abstract , but can not use generic  type of generic type.

Comment: Which Unity version are you using? If you do `public Node<IMyInterface> node;` and have an implementation like `public class MyClass : Node<IMyInterface> { }` I can drag it in via the Inspector just fine and also `GetComponent<Node<IMyInterface>()` works fine for me ... in Unity 2021

Comment: Do you have each class in its own file with matching name? I suspect that your `MyClass` script doesn't match name with the class that's why the Inspector fails to link the script file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice the interface, so I suspect you didn't declare `MyClass` as such, but in the following form:

```
class MyImpl : IMyInterface;
class MyClass : Node<MyImpl>;
```

Now everything makes sense.

Although `Node<MyImpl>` is similar to `Node<IMyInterface>`, they are actually different types, the assignment `Node<IMyInterface> node = new MyClass();` is invalid, so `GetComponent<Node<IMyInterface>>()` cannot find a component which type is `Node<MyImpl>`.

In the inspector, both `Node<MyImpl>` and `Node<IMyInterface>` fields are shown as `` Node`1 ``, it's the generic type defination (`Node<>`) of these classes, when you drag a `Node<MyImpl>` component to a `Node<IMyInterface>` field, only the defination is compared, that's why you can see the field highlights but cannot be set.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass : Node<IMyInterface>
abstract Node<T> : Monobehaviour where T : IMyInterface
PreciseClass : Monobehaviour , IMyInterface

GetComponent<MyClass >()//work
GetComponent<Node<PreciseClass>()//not work
GetComponent<PreciseClass>()//work
```

for example like this.

Comment: I suppose this is as far as OP's findings go ;) But you do not always want to use the precise class but rather the abstract parent class

Comment: @derHugo yeah i only need the parent class, don't see any alternative though

Comment: @derHugo it's like old question. have any idea to do it? dont use precise class to get compoent.